Questions about how the quarkus framework integrates with knife4j
Recently I used the swagger-ui he started on the quarkus project and found the native swagger-ui very difficult to use, and I want to port knife4j pages to the quarkus project. So I read the knife4j source code and found that knife4j essentially uses springdoc-openapi. After entering the knife4j home page, I will call the /v3/api-docs/swagger-config interface. This interface is also provided by springdoc-openapi, which returns some project documentation information and the address to get interface information, such as
{
  "configUrl": "/v3/api-docs/swagger-config",
  "oauth2RedirectUrl": "http://localhost:8085/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html",
  "operationsSorter": "alpha",
  "tagsSorter": "alpha",
  "urls": [
    {
      "url": "/v3/api-docs/default",
      "name": "default"
    }
  ],
  "validatorUrl": ""
}

The url field in the urls returns the address from which the project fetched interface information. After the /v3/api-docs/swagger-config interface returns, call /v3/api-docs/default to get the interface information. I have basically understood the knife4j process for obtaining interface data, and I plan to transplant it into my quarkus project. After introducing smallrye-openapi into my quarkus project, I can obtain interface information from /q/openapi. However, the /v3/api-docs/swagger-config interface was not provided, so I manually wrote this interface to return the relevant information needed inside. It can be used normally here, and it is considered a successful transplant. The catch is that if I were to use knife4j on other quarkus projects, I would have to repeat the above steps and write the interface separately. I decided that this was not perfect enough, so I planned to write a jar package that would allow quarkus projects to access knife4j pages and provide the /v3/api-docs/swagger-config interface required for knife4j pages. I tried to write such a jar package by myself, but I found that I couldn't do it, because to provide such an interface, I needed to create a quarkus project and introduce some dependencies such as quarkus-resteasy-reactive, so whether there would be version problems, for example: The quarkus version in the jar package I wrote is 3.2, but the version of the project that introduced this jar package is 3.11 so that there will be different versions of the problem. How do I write this jar package? Can provide http interface with address /v3/api-docs/default without version conflict problem, and can be directly used by other quarkus projects?
Expectations can be fulfilled

This is the kind of job where a quarkus extension can help. There's a tutorial on writing your first extension which covers a somewhat similar use case to yours.

Thank you very much for your information, I have now written my quarkus extension, but now I have another problem. I want to add an http filter to this extension to do some enhancements to the /q/openapi http requests provided by quarkus-smallrye-openapi. I have tried to write filters in the extension, but the filters did not work after another project introduced the extension. So how do I solve this problem?

Probably best to open a new question for that ...
